# An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, entity

I'm getting this error while trying to use Core Data:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext'

I traced the error back to this in my modal view controller which contains the Table View:

```
    - (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSString *entityName = @"Location";
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

// ERROR OCCURS IN THE LINE BELOW vvv
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

    [self performFetch];
}
```

This is what I have in my AppDelegate:

```
    - (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSString *entityName = @"Location"; 
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];



    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}
```

I get no errors there, and here's more of the App Delegate:

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            // Using abort() right now just for development
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Forecaster.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

and in my Model.xcdatamodeid:

[image: Model]

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Method:

```
    - (void)setupFetchedResultsController
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
else
{
    // your data is in array
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (FailedBankInfo *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", info.name);
    FailedBankDetails *details = info.details;
    NSLog(@"Zip: %@", details.zip);
}
```

Comment: If you put a break point near your fetch request. and got through that. Check your value of FetchRequest. It is not initializing. Thats why it might be giving issue. put it in "setupFetchedResultsController"

Comment: The results array will contain all your data.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the second line of code, it's giving me a use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: Put your entity instead of DVD.

Comment: What is my object context's object? This is my first time using Core Data, excuse my questions

Comment: * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext'

Comment: Use this link:-   http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.in/2011/03/fetch-records-in-core-data-using.html                      

http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Comment: Alright, I changed my code to what you had, and I'm getting this error: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Location'. Am I not importing something?

Comment: Check if you have imported "Location.h" in the class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14102/discussion-between-programmer20005-and-icreative)